# Unable to Profile Code Using Go Profile

Tags: go, profiling

I am trying to get a hang of Go Pro filer by following the example in go [blog](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) . I am not sure what I am doing wrong. But my profiled generated output shows 0 samples. Its weird.

```
rahul@g3ck0:~/programs/go$ go tool pprof parallel cpuprofile 
Welcome to pprof!  For help, type 'help'.
(pprof) top5  
Total: 0 samples
```

The following is my code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
    "strings"
    "runtime/pprof"
    "os"
)

func exe_cmd(cmd string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {

    out, err := exec.Command(cmd).Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error occured")
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", out)

    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
     f, _ := os.Create("cpuprofile")
     pprof.StartCPUProfile(f)
        defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()
    cmd := "echo newline >> blah.txt"
    parts := strings.Fields(cmd)
    head := parts[0]
    parts = parts[1:len(parts)]
    out, err := exec.Command(head,parts...).Output()
    if err != nil {
         fmt.Println("error occured")
         fmt.Printf("%s", err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s", out)

}
```

Comment: Well, your program is doing basically **nothing** (okay, split a string and print two lines). You cannot profile something like this. Profiling periodically looks in which functions your code is running and reports this data. Your code simple doesn't run long enough to capture a single profiling event. And no: `exec.Command` does not count.

Comment: @Volker Of course you *can* profile this program. You just have to adjust the [sampling rate of the profiler](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetCPUProfileRate). The problem here is that it is too low for the profiler to see anything and it will report 0 samples.

Comment: I admit: You *can* profile this code. But it is of no use.

Comment: It's a CPU sample rate, implying that sampling is suspended during blocking, such as I/O or your `exec.Command`. So those will not be seen, regardless of the sample rate, even if they take 99.9% of the overall time.

Comment: This is just an exercise for me to learn profiling using GO. The pprof tool doesnt show any samples yet.

Answer (score 3):

Your profiled program runs not long enough for the profiler to pick up any profiling sample.
Basically the profiler looks periodically at the state of your program (which code is executed, what function is that, ...). If the program terminates faster than the routine that looks for a status then no status is sampled and, thus, there are no samples to look at in the end.

This is what happens for you.

One solution is set the [sample rate](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetCPUProfileRate) of the profiler to a higher value, the other way
is to have your program actually do something that takes longer. For example:

```
 f, _ := os.Create("cpuprofile")

 pprof.StartCPUProfile(f)
 defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()

 for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
      time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
 }
```

Alternatively, when trying to figure out what is wrong with a isolated portion of your code,
you can write a [benchmark](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks) and profile that benchmark.